# Adding additional docker node to Shipyard

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have installed Shipyard following the automatic procedure on their website. This works and I can access the UI. It's available on ***172.31.0.179:8080***. From the UI, I see a container called 'shipyard-discovery' which is exposing ***172.31.0.179:4001***.

I'm now trying to add an additional node to Shipyard. For that I use Docker Machine to install an additional host and on that host I'm using the following command to add the node to Shipyard.

```
curl -sSL https://shipyard-project.com/deploy | ACTION=node DISCOVERY=etcd://173.31.0.179:4001 bash -s
```

This additional node is not added to the Swarm cluster and is not visible in the Shipyard UI. On that second host I get the following output

```
 -> Starting Swarm Agent
Node added to Swarm: 172.31.2.237
```

This indicated that indeed the node is not added to the Swarm cluster as I was expecting sth like: `Node added to Swarm: 172.31.0.179`

Any idea on why the node is not added to the Swarm cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation for [manual deployment](https://shipyard-project.com/docs/deploy/manual/) you can add a Swarm Agent writing it's host IP:

```
docker run \
-ti \
-d \
--restart=always \
--name shipyard-swarm-agent \
swarm:latest \
join --addr [NEW-NODE-HOST-IP]:2375  etcd://[IP-HOST-DISCOVERY]:4001
```

Comment: Does this actually work for you? It doesn't for me. If I have two machines, IP1 and IP2, and I have the automatic deploy done on IP1, as a result IP1:4001 is exposed, and I run your command with NEW-NODE-HOST-IP = IP2 and IP-HOST-DISCOVERY = IP1, it doesn't work. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've just managed to make shipyard see the nodes in my cluster, you have to follow the instructions in [Node Installation](https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2016/07/10/managing-containers-shipyard/), by creating a bash file that does the deploy for you with the discovery IP set up.